# query to pull up only those records where there is no corresponding negative value in a column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with close to 500k records. This is a place where users will add a particular record, in this case it's a coupon. At the point it's added, it has a positive '1' value, however, when this coupon gets used it get's a '-1' value. There's is also a scenario where if the coupon that was used gets returned, it gets voided in my system, and that changes the value to '1'.

here's a simplified structure:

```
CouponID    CouponVendorID   CouponValue       CouponQty    Action  Barcode
1           117             25.00             1            Add      11112
2           117            -25.00            -1            Use      11112
3           117             25.00             1            Void     11112
4           117             17.00             1            Add      33331
5           117             90.00             1            Add      44441
6           117             5.00              1            Add      42424
7           117            -5.00             -1            Use      42424
```

So what I'm trying to do is find all cards (CouponID will do), for where I still have a valid coupon.

I am able to get the correct COUNT of valid coupons by taking the Sum(couponQty) with this query

```
select 'Avail'= sum(couponQty) from tblA where CouponVendorID = 117
```

However, I'm having a hard time find the detail records showing me which CouponID's are actually included in the COUNT of valid coupons. Any idea?

Desired end result:

```
CouponID    CouponVendorID   CouponValue       CouponQty    Action  Barcode
1           117             25.00             1            Add      11112
4           117             17.00             1            Add      33331
5           117             90.00             1            Add      44441
```

CouponID = 1, was Added, then Used, then VOIDED, so it becomes still valid. CouponID = 4 was only added, and never used, same with CouponID =5.

Comment: Why do you not have a column to track the instance? Meaning if you have two coupons worth $25 you have no way of knowing which entry goes with which one.

Comment: This can be complicated, if users can have multiple coupons with the same value from the same vendor.

Comment: barcode is different for every coupon

Comment: Ahh gotcha. Seems a simple SUM would find you the barcodes that are not used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I came up with seems to do the job.

```
SELECT CouponVendorId, Barcode, 'CpnQty' = Sum(CouponQty)From tblA
GROUP BY CouponVendorId, Barcode 
HAVING CouponVendorId = 117 AND SUM(CouponQty) > 0
```

Comment: CouponVendorId should be a where clause. And since that is a number it should not use a string literal. But that is pretty much what I was thinking would work.

Comment: having couponVendorID in where clause or where I have it in the query gives me the same result. Thanks.

Comment: Right. The where clause is used to filter rows, the having clause is used to filter groups.